# Code to access Facebook Graph API with PHP SDK not working when reloading page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm writing some code to get the Facebook pages administered by a Facebook user, using Facebook Graph API. My code asks for authorization of the user and gets a token that enables it to get this information, which is then stored in a session. The problem is that if I reload the page, the stored token is unset and I will not be able to get the Facebook pages administered by the Facebook user.

The token is apparently revoked via the 'validateExpiration()' function when the page is reloaded.

What am I missing?

Here is my code:

```
session_start();

// Load the Facebook PHP SDK
require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook-sdk-v5/autoload.php';

define('APP_ID', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
define('APP_SECRET', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id'     => APP_ID,
    'app_secret' => APP_SECRET,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.7'
]);

if(isset($_SESSION['fb_access_token'])) {

  echo '$_SESSION["fb_access_token"] = ' . $_SESSION['fb_access_token'] . '<br>';

// Create a new AccessToken object from its string code. Needed?
$accessToken = new Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken($_SESSION['fb_access_token']);

  $expirationDate = $accessToken->getExpiresAt();
  echo 'Token expires at: ' . var_dump($expirationDate) . '<br>'; // Returns null!

// verifies the validity and expiration of the token
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
$tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);


try {
  echo 'Validating token<br>';
    $tokenMetadata->validateAppId(APP_ID);
    $tokenMetadata->validateExpiration(); // This apparently throws an exception

} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'I will now unset the token<br>';
    unset($accessToken);
    unset($_SESSION['fb_access_token']);
}

if(!isset($accessToken)){
  echo 'Token not set!';
  exit;
}

// Check permissions
if (isset($accessToken)) {
  $response = $fb->get('/me/permissions', $accessToken);

  $permissions = $response->getDecodedBody();
  echo 'Permissions: ';
  print_r($permissions);
  $permissions_list = [];

  foreach($permissions['data'] as $perm) {
      if($perm['status'] == 'granted') {
          $permissions_list[] = $perm['permission'];
      }
  }
  echo 'Permissions list: ';
  print_r($permissions_list);


  if(!in_array('pages_show_list', $permissions_list)) {

    echo 'I will now unset the token<br>';
    unset($accessToken);
    unset($_SESSION['fb_access_token']);
  }

}
} else {

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
}

if(isset($accessToken)) {
// Logged in!

// Save the string code of the AccessToken to re-create it later
$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

echo '$_SESSION["fb_access_token"] = ' . $_SESSION['fb_access_token'] . '<br>';

try {
    $response = $fb->get('/me/accounts', $accessToken);
    $data = $response->getDecodedBody();
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
    echo '</pre>';
    exit;

} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
} else {
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'public_profile','pages_show_list']; // Optional permissions

$redirect_url = "https://www.example.com/this_file.php";
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirect_url, $permissions);
echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it!

The problem is that the Facebook AccessToken is an object with two properties: a string code, and a datetime PHP object with the expiration time - see the code in:
[Github repository of Facebook's PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/master/src/Facebook/Authentication/AccessToken.php). The first time I get a fresh token, its expiration time is set and everything works fine. But when I store its code in a session and try to recreate it with

```
$accessToken = new Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken($_SESSION['fb_access_token']);
```

I'm not setting the expiration time, which the object defaults to the UNIX time 0 (i.e. January 1, 1970). Since after I invoke the function `validateExpiration()`, this will return that the access token has expired (it just looks at the expiration time in the AccessToken object) and will fire an exception.

**Solution:** Do not re-validate the stored token. The `validateAppId(APP_ID)` continues to be valid. For the expiration time, either store it (for example in a session) and use it when recreating the AccessToken object, or make a call to the Graph API. If this call returns an error (probably because of a token which was expired or a permission which was revoked by the user), ask the user for a new token via Facebook Login.